# closing the db connection in jdbc

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I need help in closing the connection in this following code. I've tried other closing at various locations but i'm not able to close it correctly. either it throws an exception or it shows"variable not reachable" error.This block will execute on page load

```
<%!
            public class Actor {

                String URL = "jdbc:mysql://mll-pbbvew1:3307/sakila";
                String USERNAME = "root";
                String PASSWORD = "password";

                Connection connection = null;
                PreparedStatement selectActors = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;

                public Actor() {

                    try {

                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                        selectActors = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sakila.test");
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public ResultSet getActors(String userid) {
                    try {
                        selectActors.setString(1, userid);
                        resultSet = selectActors.executeQuery();

                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return resultSet;
                }

            }


        %>
```

I have another block with insert statement in the same page which is getting closed properly. Pls help to close the connection for this select statement

edit 1:

i call the resultset at a later place like this

```
<% Actor actor = new Actor();
            ResultSet actors = actor.getActors(userid);

        %>
```

Where should i place the connection.close(); so that the connection is closed correctly

edit 2:
i get the userid as string from another HTML page as input as have

```
<%
String userid=request.getParameter("userid");
%>
```

at the very top of this jsp page

Comment: opening "in school way" is horrible un-optimal. Closing is only cosmetic change to bad solution. Such subject in production code is resolved totally different way (connection pool, JNDI)

Comment: The fact that this is in a scriptlet makes me queasy.

Comment: usually you release resources in `finally` block

Comment: In addition to the `finally` block solution, for any class implementing the Closable interface, since Java 7 there is try-with-resources which guarantees closure. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)